# Why <link using <%=rootDir%> rather than a root folder?

Tags: asp.net

Given a tree of--

```
C:\mydirINET\\Central35webapp
    example_A.aspx
    example_B.aspx
---->\App_Themes
-------->\Styles
------------SABT_template.css

There is code in Page_Load that resolves--

// get the root directory
string rootDir = page.ResolveUrl("~");

Here are two html fragments.
Are these two examples equivalent?
Why would one be used rather than another?
Are either of these customary in a particular ASP.NET version?

example_A
<link href="<%=rootDir%>/Styles/SABT_template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

example_B
<link href="/App_Themes/Styles/SABT_template.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

tkx, donPablo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`page.ResolveUrl` accounts for IIS applications which might not be rooted at the host.

If your application was in the `app` directory, `/app_themes...` would be incorrect.